# update an array in an embedded document

Tags: mongodb

I have a skill collection like this

```
"userID" : "1",
"userSkilldetailslists" : [ 
    {
        "skillID" : "1",
        "skillLists" : [ 
            "OOPS", 
            "CORE JAVA", 
            "JDBC"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "skillID" : "2",
        "skillLists" : [ 
            "SPRING", 
            "HIBERNATE"
        ]
    }
]
```

i want to add a one more string "SERVLETS" to skillLists of skillID:"1".
Please help me.Thank you

Comment: Do you want to update database or aggregate the result?

Comment: @Anthony by passing userID and skillID in query i want to update skillLists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
db.collection.update(
  { "userID": "1", "userSkilldetailslists": { "$elemMatch": { "skillID": "1" }}},
  { "$push": { "userSkilldetailslists.$.skillLists": "SERVLETS" }}
)
```

Comment: thank you very much its working

Comment: @nithin Great!!! cheers